# LAMP: browsers not supports javascript in ubuntu

Tags: javascript, php, html, ubuntu, lamp

I am using ubuntu 15.04 in vmware 12, i created a test project in `/var/www/html`, all browsers(FF,Chrome,etc) supports css but not supports javascript code, i checked with internal and external javascript also but no use.

My sample code : `/var/www/html/firstpro/index.php`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
     <head>
        <title>index</title>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!--<script src="script/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
        <script>
            function test(){
               alert('hi');
            }
        </script>
     </head>
     <body>
        <span onclick="test();">test js</span>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the issue? What is not supported?

Comment: LAMP has nothing to do with your browser. Try writing proper html and check you console for errors

Comment: Check out the corrected code if you are looking out for the `js alert` in above code.

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala - css runs fine but javascript code not runs on browers.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the corrected code if you are looking for JS alert:
`<a onclick="test();">test js</a>` This will by default reload the page. You need to update it to `<a href="#" onclick="test();">test js</a>`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
     <head>
        <title>index</title>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!--<script src="script/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
        <script>
            function test(){
               alert('hi');
            }
        </script>
     </head>
     <body>
        <a href="#" onclick="test();">test js</a>
     </body>
</html>
```

Check this JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0ba7cfwn/

Comment: yes i tried this it changes url but no alert message.

Comment: i checked with `span` javascript not runs

Comment: @151291 did you get it?

Comment: yes i got solution, the error in javascript, not in html

Comment: Oh Great! Please accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: yes your answer is useful, but not correct answer so +1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105012/discussion-between-151291-and-fakhruddin-ujjainwala).